# Can Not Use Chat

Tags: support, status-completed, chat

I have 101 Rep on meta.stackoverflow.com however, my account on chat.meta.stackoverflow.com shows me as having 1 rep.  As a result I am unable to use chat. As I understand it the rep should be identical between the two.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Meta reputation doesn't update on Chat](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57144/meta-reputation-doesnt-update-on-chat)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Has your rep changed very recently (maybe due to creating a new meta account and associating them)?

The rep is cached for about an hour, but to kick it: try navigating to [here](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/logout).

If that doesn't work, I have other tricks... let me know.